# Can Catherine for PS3 be switched to the Japanese voice actors?

Tags: ps3, catherine

I was thinking of getting Catherine for PS3 but then I found out that it looks like you might not be able to choose the Japanese voice actors and I am kind of a snob about that sort of thing. Does anyone know anything else about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to a [post in this forum](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/605302-catherine/answers?qid=277607), Aram Jabbari (the Atlus Public Relations manager) mentions the following:

> There is no Japanese audio, only English. We really, truly try to
>   explore this option wherever possible. It just wasn’t something we
>   could do for Catherine.

In the same comments section, he also says

> There is no Japanese voice option in the game. For the folks out there
>   who simply must have it, you’re right in that importing is the way to
>   go. It’d be a shame, though. We have a heck of a cast for the NA
>   release, and they do every bit of justice and then some to the
>   original audio track!

According to [this forum](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/605302-catherine/answers?qid=277607) (I do not know how legitimate this is), the developers also said the following:

> While we certainly respect your preference and, as weve stated before,
>   always explore options to include a toggle with the original Japanese
>   voices, it should be noted that Catherines story and characters
>   inhabit a generic AMERICAN city. Hence everything in Stray Sheep,
>   their attire, etc. being in English.
>
> And while we recognize the numerous comments from folks adamant that
>   its Japanese or nothing for them, we cant help but feel like those
>   gamers are going to miss out on what is, in our view, one of our best
>   localizations to date, and a fantastic English dub to boot.
>
> Again, thanks for your thoughts. Were certainly always open to
>   feedback.

Comment: +1 for `importing is the way to go. It’d be a shame, though.` - this isn't some crappy anime dub.  The English version has really, *really* good audio; and they changed the animations to match, something they can't normally do for anime.  You can see an example [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aw4poruXT0c#t=0m50s).  So, **you're not missing out by playing the NA version.**